# How does this interpolating function work?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to write a function which interpolates some data and then you can chose any value on the x axis to find the corresponding point on the y axis.

For example:

```
f = f_from_data([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
print f(3.5)
```

produces the answer

```
0.5
```

I came across an answer which looks like this:

```
def f_from_data(xs,ys):
    return scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xs, ys)
```

Can someone please explain how this works? I understand interp1d but I'm not sure how this simple line of code can get the answer when, for example

```
print f(5)
```

is input into it.

Comment: See the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example may help. `interp1d` is a class that acts like a function. It returns not a number, but another function-like object. Once you call it again, it returns the interpolated value of y at the input value of x. You can also feed this function single points, or whole arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

X=[3,4,6]
Y=[0,1,2]

f = interp1d(X,Y, bounds_error=False)
print f(3.5)

X2 = np.linspace(3, 6, 5)
print X2
print f(X2)
```

---

```
0.5
[ 3.    3.75  4.5   5.25  6.  ]
[ 0.     0.75   1.25   1.625  2.   ]
```

Comment: As Simon notes (from the docs) `interp1d` is actually a class (yes, without the cap), and `f` is an `interp1d` object with a `.__call__` method.  So both look like functions, even if they are not.

Comment: @hpaulj That's a good point (I'll update my answer), but I think OP was having trouble understanding how to use the function (but I may just be inferring from the accept). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses linear interpolation - straight connecting lines between data points.

So, for your given data (`xs = [3, 4, 6]` and `ys = [0, 1, 2]`) the function looks like

[image: chart of interpolated function]

where the blue points are the input data, the green line is the interpolated function, and the red dot is the test point `f(3.5) == 0.5`

---

To calculate `f(5.0)`:

First, you have to find out which line segment you are on.

`x == 5` is in the second segment, between 4 and 6, so we are looking for point `C (5, y)` between points `A (4, 1)` and `B (6, 2)`.

`C` is on the line, so `AC = k * AB` where `0. <= k < 1.`; this gives us two equations in two unknowns (`k` and `y`). Solving, we get

```
y = Ay + (By - Ay) * (Cx - Ax) / (Bx - Ax)
```

and subbing in,

```
y = 1. + (2. - 1.) * (5. - 4.) / (6. - 4.)
  = 1.5
```

so the interpolated point is `C (5, 1.5)` and the function returns `f(5.0) = 1.5`

---

From the above, you should be able to write your own `f()` function given `xs` and `ys`; and this is exactly what `scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xs, ys)` does - takes `xs` and `ys` and returns an interpolative function, ie

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])

# f is now a function that you can call, like
f(5.0)      # =>  1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
This class returns a function whose call method uses interpolation 
to find the value of new points.
```

Thus, calling the returned function with an `x` value gives the corresponding interpolated `y` value.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks I looked at that but I'm not sure what it means by "call method".

Comment: The documentation is describing the function as an object. Executing the "call method" on the function just calls the function.

Comment: `f` has a `__call__` method.  This is called when you use `f(...)`.  `callable(f)` returns `True`.